# How to pull data from MongoDB without the JSON using IPython

Tags: json, mongodb, ipython

I've managed to get this far:

```
import json
import pymongo
from bson import json_util
from pymongo import Connection

c = Connection()
db = c.test
collection = db.messages
for doc in collection.find({"mailbox":"bass-e"}, { "body" : "true" }):
    doc
print doc
```

But what comes out is a JSON object. What I want is just the data. What packages/methods do I need to use to just get the text in the body column?

Comment: you mean `print doc.body`?

Comment: That throws an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection

c = Connection()
db = c.test
collection = db.messages
messages = []
for doc in collection.find({"mailbox":"bass-e"}, { "body" : "true" }).limit(3):
    messages.append(doc["body"])

for x in messages:
    print x
```